# What is special about Holy Damage?

Tags: diablo-iii

Many Monk items and skills add plus to *Holy Damage*. Is Holy Damage unique in any way, or is it treated just like other elemental damage types? Will monsters eventually show up who are resistant to Holy Damage much like Fire, Cold, ect...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most (and only) interesting aspect of Holy Damage is that it shares a resistance with Arcane: Arcane/Holy resistance.

Considering how often the minions of hell use holy damage, this was done to avoid giving the player a resistance that was scarcely used.

Comment: There is speculation about Holy Damage hitting Undead enemies harder. Do you know anything about that?

Comment: @Emerica. Only that it's [being discussed elsewhere](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/66811/336).

Answer (score 0):

I recall someone mentioning on this site that at least on Weapons, Frost damage has a chance to slow, Fire to apply a burn dot (similar to poison), Lightning to briefly stun and **Holy to splash healing around the hit target** (to any friendly melees including yourself).

At least, as said, it shares resistance with Arcane.