# Diablo 3 Weapon / Skill Elemental Attributes

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “elemental” damage on weapons work with elemental skills?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63646/how-does-elemental-damage-on-weapons-work-with-elemental-skills)
>   [Is magical/enchanted damage more effective against certain types of monsters than others?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66811/is-magical-enchanted-damage-more-effective-against-certain-types-of-monsters-tha)

I've been playing Diablo 3 for a while now, but i've never really bothered about the elemental attributes of a weapon itself (for example, an Arcane-based weapon, etc).

I know there are 6 different attributes to a weapon, namely:

**Arcane**

**Cold**

**Fire**

**Holy**

**Lightning**

**Poison**

But how does it affect the mobs you attack?

Does an Arcane weapon deal reduced damage, say 70% to an Arcane monster?

What if its versus a Fire monster? Would it deal an extra percentage, say 110% maybe?

Is there a chart for this?

Comment: this is NOT a duplicate. i am saying if your elemental skill affects the damage on the monsters you attack with. Like Lightning vs a Fallen

Comment: i'm looking for a percentage chart. not a wall of text. and the results for that answer is incomplete. There are 7 elemental attributes, he only covered 4.

Comment: The appropriate solution to a duplicate question with an unsatisfactory answer is to post a bounty seeking an improved answer. As you can see, someone has already done that in this case, though a better answer hasn't yet come along. Posting a new question is *not* an appropriate solution.

Comment: i am intending to add a bounty.

Comment: LessPop's 2nd link is what you want, note that unless Diablo has minions using Holy power ... basically, Holy will always do 100% damage while any others will encounter a few enemies that take 20% less dmg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mobs can be strong against a certain element, and will do reduced damage to them. The rest will always do 100% damage. So a Ice vs a fire monster will do 100% normal damage, the same as lighting.

Comment: If you could create a chart based on what element affects what element and to what percentage, it would be a better answer.

Comment: @RenoYeo - I think you're misunderstanding the answer.  What Halfwarr is saying here is that all damage types do 100% to everything unless that monster is resistant.  So, an Arcane resistant monster just takes less damage from Arcane *but everything else is unaffected*.  This works just like the player character's elemental resists.  There's no chart to create.